# How can I return the index of a header tag from HTML into an Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, html

I want to get some information from a website in HTML onto an Excel sheet. The structure of this information is such that there is a heading, which has an ID, and underneath, a corresponding paragraph, which has no such ID.  I know I can access the header with

```
=IMPORTXML(URL,"//h3[@id='ID']"),
```

is there a way I can get a cell to return the index? With this I would then plan to

```
=IMPORTXML(URL,"//p[index]")
```

And be able to build a table out of this information, which would hopefully be more robust than just pointing it to the current index numerically (which would be subject to change if they added more headers or paragraphs).

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If I understand right, you want to programatically assign the cell, as in grab part of the text on cell C1 and from there deduce you need cell D4 and use a function to retrieve D4? is that correct?